# Read JSON from file UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I newer in creating Universal Apps

I have JSON in .txt file. Image and TextBox  in xaml

I need to read JSON from .txt and parse text from JSON to TextBox. 
For Image i need to download it via url, that in JSON

My JSON

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Ролл Чеддер c темпура креветкой
            [post_excerpt] => Рис, нори, темпура креветка, сыр филадельфия, огурец, сыр чеддер, соус голландский

            [img_url] => http://new.murakami.ua/wp-content/uploads/535_520Rol-chedr-s-sirom-filadelfiej-i-tempura-krevetkoyu.jpg
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 124.00
            [weight] => 195/16
            [sku] => 233
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Ролл спайси лосось
            [post_excerpt] => Рис, нори, лосось, спайси соус, икра масаго, зеленый лук
            [img_url] => http://new.murakami.ua/wp-content/uploads/535_520Rol-spajsi-losos.jpg
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 68.00
            [weight] => 130/16
            [sku] => 239
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Ролл с пастрами

            [post_excerpt] => Рис, нори, пастрами, листья салата, перец болгарский, огурец, соус горчичный, помидор, голландский соус 

            [img_url] => http://new.murakami.ua/wp-content/uploads/535_520Rol-z-pastrami.jpg
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 98.00
            [weight] => 185/16
            [sku] => 245
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Ролл огуречный лосось

            [post_excerpt] => Рис, нори, лосось, сыр филадельфия, сладкий омлет, икра тобико, огурец, голландский соус

            [img_url] => http://new.murakami.ua/wp-content/uploads/535_520Rol-ogirkovij-losos.jpg
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 112.00
            [weight] => 190/16
            [sku] => 244
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Ролл оши абури с лососем и голландским соусом

            [post_excerpt] => Рис, лосось, огурец, перец чили, голландский соус

            [img_url] => http://new.murakami.ua/wp-content/uploads/535_520Oshi-aburi-z-lososem-i-golandskim-sousom.jpg
            [visibility] => visible
            [price] => 98.00
            [weight] => 18016
            [sku] => 240
        )
```

How I do it in Adroid via Xamarin

```
 var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "cache3.txt");
        JsonValue readJson;
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        readJson = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);



  private async void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue readJson)
    {



        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.weight);
        ImageView imagen = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image1);
        ImageButton add = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.add);
        add.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BludoDetail));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
        productname.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent485 = new Intent(this, typeof(BludoDetail));
            StartActivity(intent485);
        };
        JsonValue firstitem = readJson[0];

        productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
        price.Text = firstitem["price"] + " грн";
        weight.Text = firstitem["weight"];//"г";


        Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(imagen, firstitem["img_url"], null, 5000000);
    }
```

In Xamarin.Android I had Koush plugin, for download and cache image

How Can I parse info from Json to TextBox in UWP and how can I download image and cache it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse json.

The you should create a class that handles json and use bindings in order to combine data with xaml. In order to download image use `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

To read files from all locations [check this link](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html) and then to parse it you can use [Json.Net package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) like this

```
    public IJsonData ParseWithJObjectParse(string json, string episodesName, string titleName)
{
    var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    var items = obj.GetValue(episodesName).Select(
e => new JsonItem(((JObject)e).GetValue(titleName).ToString()));

    var jsonItems = items.Cast<IJsonItem>().ToArray();
    var result = new JsonData
    {
        Items = jsonItems
    };

    return result;
}
```

If you want then you can also use [Simple.Json](http://simplejson.codeplex.com/) and [Microsoft.Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225267.aspx) but I prefer Json.Net for its easiness.

For second part BitmapImage automatically caches remote images by default. It's best used in conjunction with CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation" for the best performance.

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0">
<Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImgURL}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

If you want to control caching yourself then [check this link.](http://chandermani.blogspot.in/2012/05/caching-images-downloaded-from-web-on.html)

Comment: For UriSource, I have my url in json , what I need to write there?

Comment: And first your link is for win 8, I writing app for win 10 mobile (uwp)

Comment: As I understood, I need to download images in .cs file, not in xaml

Comment: It would work there too. I have used it for parsing as both are based on Xaml and if you only want to cache images and not for offline access then use my method but if you want to save images locally and use it offline also or something like that then download. Hope it clears your doubt. If you clearify your case then more proper answer can be provided